# What is this flower with five mottled green petals that are fused together?

Tags: identification, flowers, succulents

[image]Does anybody know what this is? My colleague photographed it. It seems to be some kind of orchid.
The owner said it was an "umbrella plant."[image]

[image]

The flower is in a pot, 30 cm high, flowers about 3 x 2 cm. It's a climber - that's it climbing in the background. The leaves are oval and fleshy.

Comment: a description or picture of the plant and leaves would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flower is on a plant in the genus Ceropegia. Without seeing a leaf I cannot tell the species.

Another species in the genus that is a common house plant is string of hearts or rosary vine, *Ceropagia woodii*.

Comment: Appears to be [Ceropegia sandersonii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceropegia_sandersonii).

Comment: Agree, Ceropegia sandersonii - common names Parachute Plant, Umbrella plant. What an amazing thing...

Comment: @Stephie -its definitely amazing and a curiosity, but I don't find it particularly attractive, so wouldn't want one inside, though outdoors, fantastic! Not possible in the UK though...

Comment: That is amazing. I will actually go to the garden centre and try to get one now.